# convert dictionary or list to byte[]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, prime31

Ok, i've seen many similar questions both on here and unity forums asking about converting from one format to another. I've got a (hopefully) simple question that i just can't find the answer for.  I'm using the game-center plugin from Prime31 to handle a turn based multi-player game.  Inside the plugin for Prime31 they ask you for a byte[] to send to the other players. (State data) So the question is, what would be a good way to convert a List to a byte array AND then convert them back from byte array?

for reference this is as complicated a class as i need, i might need to add more members later, but not any different types. ALSO the list of int's(cards in hand) could easily be 4 separate int if that makes converting the list of PokerPlayers to an byte[] any easier.  Also at this list is not a set length but will always be 4-8.

```
public class PokerPlayer{   
    public string playerID;
    public string alias;
    public int wildCard;
    public List<int> cardsInHand;
    public int chips;   
}
```

I feel like the when i see the answer I'm going to smack myself for not seeing the answer sooner.  Any pointers/ links to relevant materials would be sweet, i've searched google for a good 3 hours now with similar (SO similar) but not quite the same questions.

Comment: Question, do you only need the list put into an array, or the whole PokerPlayer object should be transferred to somewhere else?

Comment: What i was doing was trying to convert a list of these PokerPlayers into a byte[] to send over the air thru gamecenter.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You may want to try serialization.

```
var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var mStream = new MemoryStream();
binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, myObjToSerialize);

//This gives you the byte array.
mStream.ToArray();
```

And then if you want to turn the byte array back into an object:

```
var mStream = new MemoryStream();
var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

// Where 'objectBytes' is your byte array.
mStream.Write (objectBytes, 0, objectBytes.Length);
mStream.Position = 0;

var myObject = binFormatter.Deserialize(mStream) as YourObjectType;
```

### Update:

Microsoft warns about using [`BinaryFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter) because it is "insecure and can't be made secure".

Please read [aka.ms/binaryformatter](https://aka.ms/binaryformatter) for more details.

> **Preferred alternatives**
>
> > .NET offers several in-box serializers that can handle untrusted data safely:
> >
> > - [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer) and [`DataContractSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer) to serialize object graphs into and from XML. Do not confuse `DataContractSerializer` with [`NetDataContractSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer).
> > - [`BinaryReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader) and [`BinaryWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter) for XML and JSON.
> > - The [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json) APIs to serialize object graphs into JSON.

Comment: Awesome this was the way to go, i had to google getting the list back from the byte array, but it lead me to the right answer. So much thanks.

Comment: Hi its dont work for me, u can help ? IConvertible. in System.Convert.ChangeType

Comment: Please check out https://aka.ms/binaryformatter. Microsoft's warning about using `BinaryFormatter` "The `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize` method is never safe when used with untrusted input.".

Answer (score 10):

`BinaryFormatter` is now a security risk. If I find a good way to do this without using it I'll be back

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete

Edit:
This is still the top result in Google so I'll show what I've done to move away from `BinaryFormatter`

You need Newtonsoft.Json

```
public static class ExtendedSerializerExtensions
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    };

    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(this T source)
    {
        var asString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source, SerializerSettings);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(asString);
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this byte[] source)
    {
        var asString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(source);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(asString);
    }
}
```

It's not very far to go from here if you need a stream rather than a byte array

Answer (score 1):

Converting data into byte stream (and back) is called `serialization` (and deserialization).

You can use the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to do so.