# MemoryStream.ToArray() return empty array if StreamWriter is not disposed

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I'm trying to get array of bytes from my model to put it in the file. I have a method as such:

```
        public static byte[] GetByteArray(List<MyModel> models)
    {
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);

        foreach (var model in models)
        {
            sw.Write(model.Id + "," + model.Name);
            sw.WriteLine();
        }

        sw.Dispose();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

This method works fine, but as may think I don't need to dispose *StreamWriter* manually, cause I have a using statement. I thought as well, but when I remove `sw.Dispose();` the `ms.ToArray();` returns an empty array. Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the line:

```
using var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
```

This only disposes the `StreamWriter` at the end of the method. However you're calling `ms.ToArray()` *before* the end of the method. This means that you're calling `ms.ToArray()` before the `StreamWriter` is disposed.

However, the `StreamWriter` is buffering some data internally, and only flushes this out to the `MemoryStream` when it is disposed. You therefore need to make sure you dispose the `StreamWriter` *before* calling `ms.ToArray()`.

It's probably clearer to use the older `using` syntax, which is explicit about when the disposal happens:

```
public static byte[] GetByteArray(List<MyModel> models)
{
    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        foreach (var model in models)
        {
            sw.Write(model.Id + "," + model.Name);
            sw.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: The StreamWriter takes ownership (yep, I don't like that construct either). The memorystream doesn't need to be disposed.

Comment: Yes, and strictly speaking it's being accessed after being disposed as well. However `MemoryStream.ToArray()` is safe to this, and all objects are safe to being disposed multiple times

Comment: I don't like the idea of disposing multiple times.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Classes must be written to be safe to being disposed multiple times, and in cases like this it results in code which is IMO clearer and more obviously correct, since you don't need to remember whether `StreamWriter` takes ownership of the `Stream` in order to clearly see that the code does the right thing

Comment: I agree on that, it's part of the disposing pattern, Perhaps I am (overly) precise in structure. The thing is (for example). If you open a FileStream and you create a StreamWriter on it. When the streamwriter is disposed, you are not able to use the filestream anymore. (but thats something else, how streamwriter is implemented. I probably would use the `leaveOpen` overload always ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The dispose does part of the job. It flushes the writer. Use `Flush()` to flush it manually.

```
public static byte[] GetByteArray(List<MyModel> models)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);

    foreach (var model in models)
    {
        sw.Write(model.Id + "," + model.Name);
        sw.WriteLine();
    }

    // flush the writer, to make sure it is written to the stream.
    sw.Flush();
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

You don't need to dispose the memory stream, because the StreamWriter takes ownership.

I don't like the construct that the streamwriter takes ownage of the memory stream. This is probably because there the streamwriter can also be used directly on a file. A constructor which has a file path as parameter. *(so no stream parameter is needed)*

[StreamWriter leaveOpen constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Int32_System_Boolean_)

Comment: Or set `new StreamWriter(ms) { AutoFlush = true };`

Comment: There's little point in having both `using` and `sw.Dispose()` here

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. I think the OP is asking why they needed the explicit `sw.Dispose()` when they already have a `using` statement. Adding an additional redundent `sw.Flush()` call doesn't explain this (and it's unnecessary, as the `sw.Dispose()` is already flushing).

Comment: True, it was a copy/paste mistake. The dispose of the memorystream can be removed.

Comment: Incredibly, both `AutoFlush` and manually calling `.Flush()` stopped working for me in the latest .Net. Now disposting the `StreamWriter` early seems to be _required_, as insane as that sounds.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You need to dispose it before calling `ms.ToArray()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you writing `List<MyModel>` items as strings, you can simplify conversion by:

```
public static byte[] GetByteArray(List<MyModel> models) =>
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                                       models.Select(model => $"{model.Id},{model.Name}")));
```

Or use third-party serializers, such from *Newtonsoft.Json* (example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66106760/11642651)):

```
public static byte[] Serialize<T>(this T source)
{
    var asString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source, SerializerSettings);
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(asString);
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(this byte[] source)
{
    var asString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(source);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(asString);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but Newtonsoft.Json  would need more tweaks to get the same result.
By default it would serialize all properties, not just id and name.

Comment: @Charles, I can serialize only some properties and deserialize them back to MyModel. Yep, i lose other properties (which I not include on serializing), but it is possible: https://dotnetfiddle.net/A8NJep

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned you have to Flush the `StreamWriter`
This is what your function looks like:

```
public static byte[] GetByteArray(List<MyModel> models)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        try
        {
            List<MyModel>.Enumerator enumerator = models.GetEnumerator();
            try
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    MyModel current = enumerator.Current;
                    streamWriter.Write(string.Concat(current.Id, ",", current.Name));
                    streamWriter.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                ((IDisposable)enumerator).Dispose();
            }
            streamWriter.Dispose();
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (streamWriter != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)streamWriter).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (memoryStream != null)
        {
            ((IDisposable)memoryStream).Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```